# How can I prevent my Windows partitions from being visible from my Ubuntu installation?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

I have a pretty happy setup with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.4 dual booting.  It's all working fine but I'm annoyed that I can see the Windows partitions (there are two, since it seems to have carved an extra one out for system recovery) from Ubuntu.  It doesn't auto mount them or anything, but they are there in the "Places" menu.  I would like to never be able to see them from my Ubuntu system.  How can I make them invisible?

Comment: Why? (15 chars)

Comment: Ignore them? What Linux system is responsible for creating the "Places"? It should have a config file you can edit to exclude the path.

Comment: @amphetamachine as noted in the question, Ubuntu 10.4

Answer (score 1):

Check /etc/fstab and comment out the lines for the windows partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this one, "Removing shortcuts from places" will help? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=885661 Head to the bottom.

I don't use Ubuntu (at the moment ;) so I can't vouch for the solution.